# Nodejs OPENSSH - Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead

Tags: node.js, ssh, openssh

In one node.js script, I am using openssh to execute dos command from one windows server to another remote windows server. The remote server has openssh server running and i have tested it in ssh shell,

```
ssh Administrator@hostname
```

But this does not work when I try from node.js. Here is the code which i am using ,

```
var SSH = require('simple-ssh');
var command = 'dir /b' //or dir 
ssh = new SSH({
            host: 'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX',
            user: 'Administrator',
            pass: 'password'
        });

ssh.exec(command, {
    out: function(stdout) {
        console.log(stdout);
    }
}).start(); 

ssh.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('In Start, something went wrong.');
            console.log(err);           
            ssh.end();
        });
```

Above script throws error,

```
In Start, something went wrong.
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  level: 'client-socket' }
```

please note, this gives output when i put "ls" as command , along with same error message. Ultimately I want to execute one bat file with some input parameters on remote windows server. I am not getting idea of this error and how to handle this.

I installed openssh on windows 10 VM , following url,
http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/07/30/how-to-install-openssh-on-windows-10/

And here is my windows virtual machine , C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\etc\sshd_config file content,

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options change a
# default value.

Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO
LogLevel DEBUG3

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCreds yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of 'PermitRootLogin without-password'.
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none   

# default banner path
Banner /etc/banner.txt

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/sbin/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Thanks

Comment: what happen if `var command = 'dir';` ?

Comment: it gives same ECONNRESET error.

Comment: Show your OpenSSH server config, please

Comment: Hi @Styx, do you want me to share sshd.config file ?

Comment: @usersam Yes, please.

Comment: @Styx, added sshd_config file content to question , along with the installation url.

Comment: Did you give your user account permissions to read / execute for openssh folder? https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1035 - Also - are you running Node as the administrator?

Comment: Hi @Mavi, the OpenSSH folder has full control to user(Administrator).

Comment: @usersam This  helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55669800/node-js-connection-error-econnreset-on-remote-windows-ssh

Comment: What is your node version?

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález , I only posted that answer and that does not work here. @ Atish my node version is v10.15.3.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by default ssh2 will send an application-level ping/keepalive packet every minute. That can be adjusted of course.
Configure the openssh server. ClientAlive* is the server settings, and ServerAlive* is the client settings.

https://www.simplified.guide/ssh/disable-timeout

Comment: Hi @Pablo, Thanks for such valuable information.I tried disabling SSH timeout from server but it did not work. This anyway will not solve the problem as I need to execute bat file on remote server.

Answer (score 0):

After putting lots of effort, I figured out that openssh only can execute commands which are present in "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\bin" in remote server. It is failing for command "dir" because it is not present in bin folder but works for "ls" command. It works when we put desired bat file in openssh/bin folder. I had tried putting a dummy bat file,

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\utility\run.bat" "variable1" "variable2"
exit /b
```

we can call this bat file in ssh command

```
var SSH = require('simple-ssh');
var command = 'dummy.bat'  
ssh = new SSH({
            host: 'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX',
            user: 'Administrator',
            pass: 'password'
        });

ssh.exec(command, {
    out: function(stdout) {
        console.log(stdout);
    }
}).start(); 

ssh.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('In Start, something went wrong.');
            console.log(err);           
            ssh.end();
        });
```

Though it throws ECONNRESET error but executes desired bat file.

I am not sure if this can be achieved by any other setting change. This is just a  workaround for solving the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solve it for a long time, I struggle for these the ssh to a remote server frequently, and the connection can not be closed by `ssh.compose()` in the ssh-node package, and I find remote windows ssh server still generate many processes named `sshd` process and not be closed, and after `ssh.compose`, the node.js will throw the error `Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead` which can not be caught by code.I find many references, it could be the `TCP` connection is still working on and not be closed. So I try to refer to the ssh-node code and use the

`ssh.connection.destroy()`

which point to the `Client.prototype.destroy` method in `ssh2` package， so the error `Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead` will disappeared, and the connection will be closed totally.